# Is there a way to print the page/line numbers for each erratum using the `errata` LaTeX package?

Tags: books, proofreading

I'd like to be able to track errata in a thesis consisting of multiple LaTeX files, then display them in a separate document. Using the [`errata`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/errata?lang=en) package I am able to do something like this:

`thebook.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hide, record]{errata}

\title{The Book}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{First section}
I misspelled a \erratumReplace{misspelled `word'}{ord}{word} on this line.

\section{Second section}
... and also on this \erratumReplace{misspelled `line'}{ine}{line}.

\end{document}
```

`theerrata.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hide]{errata}

\title{Errata in The Book}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\printerrata{thebook}
\end{document}
```

Which gives me:

[image]

Is there any way that I could print the page number as well as the section/subsection for each erratum? The [`errata` documentation](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/errata/errata.pdf) says:

> Their location will be referenced by the section they appear in rather than the page number, since we do not expect the former to change in the errata correction process.

In my particular case, however, I need more positional information about each erratum - the page number at the very least, and if possible, the line number as well. Is there any way to achieve this using `errata` or some other package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to persuade the package to do this out-of-the-box. However, we can patch the command it uses to create the references for the errata which it writes to the `-errata.tex` file when `record` is active.

For example, using `etoolbox`, we can add the page number to the sectioning information as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hide, record]{errata}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\apptocmd\ErratumRef{: p.~\arabic{page}}{\typeout{Successfully added pages to errata references.}}{\typeout{Oh no! Could not add pages to errata references. Patch failed!}}
\title{The Book}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{First section}
I misspelled a \erratumReplace{misspelled `word'}{ord}{word} on this line.
\clearpage
No errors here!
\clearpage
\section{Second section}
\dots and also on this \erratumReplace{misspelled `line'}{ine}{line}.
\end{document}
```

I extended the MWE a little just to test that I wasn't getting all page numbers equal to 1 or equal to the current section number or something. The above produes the following `-errata.tex` file:

```
\erratumItem{{}1: p.\nobreakspace  {}1}{misspelled `word'}
\erratumItem{{}2: p.\nobreakspace  {}3}{misspelled `line'}
```

When the list of errata

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hide]{errata}
\title{Errata in The Book}
\begin{document}
  \maketitle
  \printerrata{<filename of The Book>}
\end{document}
```

is processed, this produces

[image: more informative errata]

---

Line numbers are significantly trickier and well beyond the ken of this answer's author. Although I've never used it before, however, the `lineno` package may be of help here.

## *Caveat emptor ...*

---

The package offers various options but not all of these are likely to be usable for our purpose. The most robust option is probably to simply load the package with the default options and say `\linenumbers` before `\maketitle`.

In that case, the original document looks like this on pages 1 and 3:

[image: line numbers page 1] 
[image: line numbers page 3]

and we can amend our patch

```
\apptocmd\ErratumRef{: p.~\arabic{page}: l.~\arabic{linenumber}}{\typeout{Successfully added pages to errata references.}}{\typeout{Oh no! Could not add pages to errata references. Patch failed!}}
```

to produce the following in the errata document

[image: line numbers in errata]

If we prefer not to display line numbers in the original document we can add

```
\let\makeLineNumber\relax
```

and the references for the errata will still pick up the line numbers. However, this will make the line numbers significantly less useful as we will be left to guess where on page 54 line 1,023 is or whatever. If there are a lot of errata, this is probably manageable, but if errata on a page are sparse, the line number will be almost useless.

`lineno` supports resetting the page numbers on each page. However, this will not work straightforwardly with `errata`. Moreover, the conditions `lineno` imposes for this option are unlikely to be satisfied by a typical thesis. For example, many theses use lower-case Roman numerals for the 'front matter' before switching to Arabic. This would require a great deal of care and probably switching between different kinds of line numbers in the document - and that's before even thinking about making it work with `errata` as well. See `lineno`'s documentation for further details of its features and pitfalls.

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hide, record]{errata}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lineno}
\apptocmd\ErratumRef{: p.~\arabic{page}: l.~\arabic{linenumber}}{\typeout{Successfully added pages to errata references.}}{\typeout{Oh no! Could not add pages to errata references. Patch failed!}}
\title{The Book}
\begin{document}
\linenumbers
\maketitle
\section{First section}
I misspelled a \erratumReplace{misspelled `word'}{ord}{word} on this line.
\clearpage
No errors here!
\clearpage
\section{Second section}
\dots and also on this \erratumReplace{misspelled `line'}{ine}{line}.
\end{document}
```

The code for the errata document remains as listed above.

Comment: Excellent answer! I will have a play around with `lineno` to see whether I can find a workable solution for my document, but just having the page numbers of the errata is already a major improvement to my workflow.

Comment: Yes, the line numbers are much trickier and the method above is not ideal at all. I couldn't come up with anything better, but I thought maybe somebody else would. I guess not - or not yet. I'm glad that the page numbers will help, though.

Answer (score 2):

I started using the errata package for my master's thesis. However, I quickly found it to be too limited, so I started modifying it and basically ended up rewriting it completely.

I extended it extensively while trying to ensure backwards compatibility. Unfortunately, I never got to publish it on ctan, so at the moment it's necessary to copy the package files from the git repo into your working dir.

Be warned, the package internals are pretty complex, so fully understanding how to utilize the options and customizing the behaviour requires a good understanding of LaTeX as well as the pkgkeys package.

Resources for the errata modifications:

- [Development repository](https://github.com/bendikro/LaTeX-errata/commits/development)
- [Manual (PDF)](https://github.com/bendikro/LaTeX-errata/blob/development/errata.pdf):
- [Example document PDF](https://github.com/bendikro/LaTeX-errata/blob/development/erratatest.pdf) and [source (erratatest.tex)](https://github.com/bendikro/LaTeX-errata/blob/development/erratatest.tex)

Among many options, you can display the page number and line number for each erratum with the option **linenos=true**.

I've made an example based on [erratatest.tex](https://github.com/bendikro/LaTeX-errata/blob/development/erratatest.tex) from the Github repo and tried to strip it down as much as possible:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1.6in,marginparsep=3mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{etextools}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{marginnote}

% Needed for line numbers
\usepackage{lineno}

\setpagewiselinenumbers
\linenumbers
% Remove the line numbers in the margin when using the lineno package
\renewcommand{\LineNumber}{}

\usepackage[bookmarks,breaklinks,pdfpagelabels,
colorlinks=true,  % Colors links instead of ugly boxes
linkcolor=black,  % Color of internal links
]{hyperref}[2012/11/06] % Reference package, must be before cleveref

\usepackage[noabbrev,nameinlink]{cleveref}[2013/12/28]


\usepackage[
margins=true,
foots=true,
record=true,
linenos=true,
defaultargs={margin=true,foot=true},
defaultargsnote={inlinechange=false},
%requirecmddescription=false,
%marginnote=false,
marginnote=true,
uniquelistlabels=0,
inlinemarks=false,
%inlinechanges=false,
inlinemarks=true,
styles={tablelist},
]{errata}[2015/04/16]

% change margin node format to use tcolorbox
\errataSetKeyFormat[#1+#2]{marginfmt/marginnote}{%
{\vspace{-4pt}%
\begin{tcolorbox}[size=fbox,nobeforeafter,
    colframe=red!50!white,colback=red!25!yellow!5!white,%
    fontupper=\scriptsize,%
    bottomrule=1pt,toprule=1pt,leftrule=0pt,rightrule=0pt,
%    arc=0cm, outer arc=0mm, % Remove the rounded corners
    arc=0cm,
    outer arc=0mm, % Remove the rounded corners
    code={\pgfkeysalsofrom#1}
    ]#2\end{tcolorbox}}}%

\makeatletter

% Example on changing the table styling
\errataset{%
  customliststyletablekeyformats/.style={%
    listformats/lineref/.setStrKeyFmt={##1}{~(L \lineref{##1})},
    %%
    listformats/erratalistbegin/.setStrKeyFmt={##1}{%
      \setlength\LTleft{-1cm}
      \setlength\LTright{-1cm}
      \makeatletter%
      \begin{longtable}{ c@{\tcolsep{1.7}} c@{\tcolsep{2}} c p{15em} l c }%
        & Title & Type & Action & Page
       },
    listformats/erratalistend/.setStrKeyFmt={##1}{\end{longtable}\makeatother},
    actionformat/replace/.setStrKeyFmt={##1+##2}{##2 \shortarrow ##1},
    actionformat/add/.setStrKeyFmt={##1}{##1},
    actionformat/delete/.setStrKeyFmt={##1}{##1},
    actionformat/note/.setStrKeyFmt={##1}{ ##1},
    footformats/description/.setStrKeyFmt={##1}{~[##1]~},
    footformats/erratumcustomlocation/.setStrKeyFmt={##1+##2}{~[P:\pageref{##1} (L \lineref{##2})]},
    listformats/erratumcustomlocation/.setStrKeyFmt={##1+##2}{\pageref{##1} (L \lineref{##2})},
    setCmdKeyArgsGetTwo={erratumcustomlocation}{##1+##2}{{pageref}+{lineref}},
  },
  customliststylefortable/.code={
    \errataSetListFormat{+erratumlistitemtitle,+erratumlisttarget,%
      \noexpand\errataamersand,+erratumnamedlink,\noexpand\errataamersand,%
      +action,\noexpand\errataamersand,+actiondescription,\noexpand\errataamersand,%
      -erratumcustomlocation}%
    \errataSetFootFormat{+description, +actiondescription, -erratumcustomlocation}
    \setcounter{@errata@uniquelistlabels}{4}
    \usepackage{stmaryrd}
    \newcommand{\shortarrow}{\ensuremath{\vrule height 2\fontdimen22\textfont2 width 0pt\shortrightarrow}}
    \newcommand{\tcolsep}[1]{\hspace{##1em}}
    \errataRegisterFormatKey{erratumcustomlocation}
  },
  styles/customtablelist/.style={styles/tablelist, customliststyletablekeyformats,
    customliststylefortable},
}

% Apply the custom table style with line numbers in errata
\errataset{.errataapplystyles/.list={customtablelist}}

\makeatother

\title{The Book}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}\label{sect:first}
I misspelled a \erratumReplace{typo}{ord}{word} on this line.

\section{Second section}

... and also on this \erratumReplace[margin=false]{typo}{ine}{line}, but hide
the note in the margin.

On this line we \erratumReplace[inlinemark=false,
label={typolabel}]{typo}{fixes}{fix} a typo and hide the inline marking, but we
still find \cref{typolabel} in the \cref{chap:errata}.

\section{Third section}

Here we \erratumAdd[foot=false]{add}{add} a word without a footnote comment.

\section{Errata}\label{chap:errata}

\PrintErrata

\end{document}
```

Looks as follows ([PDF](https://github.com/bendikro/LaTeX-errata/raw/development/errata_table_lineno.pdf)): [image]